# Excel bar chart with gradient values (not percentages) and value lines

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to create a bar chart that has a gradient fill specific to static values and then a line to indicate the actual value.

My data is like so:

```
Name Time
A    16
B    33
C    40
D    45
```

And my gradient static values I want are:

```
0 - 20 Green
21 - 30 Yellow
31 - 50 Red
```

Currently i have:

[image]

I want my output to look like so and only have the border(line) on the right hand side:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this chart answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34770582/4717755) and see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.

The important piece here is the `Bar` column. So setup your data to look like this:

[image]

1. Select the `Name`, `Green`, `Yellow`, and `Red` columns (including the headers) and then create a "Stacked Bar Chart". Once you have the chart, change the bar colors to match the color ranges. You'll have this:

   [image]
2. Select the "Time" column (including header) and Copy, then select the chart and Paste Special (add cells as new series). You'll get this:

   [image]
3. Next, select the "Time" series on the chart. You can either select it with the mouse or from the Format ribbon using the "Current Selection" group on the far left. Once it's selected, use the formatting options to select "Series Options" and plot the Time data series on the Secondary Axis:

[image]

4. Notice in my example that the primary and secondary axis are using different scales. I adjusted both these axis to a Maximum of 50. Then set the secondary Axis Label position to "None".
5. Now Copy the "Bar" data column and Paste Special onto the chart. Select that series and assign it to the secondary axis. Set the fill color to BLACK. I changed the seconardy axis Gap Width to 80% to make it stand out a bit more.

   [image]
6. Last step -- select the "Time" data series and set the Fill color to "No Fill". I made some other formatting clean up to match your chart (title="Time", deleted the Legend).

[image]

An extra formatting step you can do is to change the values in the "Bar" column to change the thickness of your black indicator.