# Overlayed Stacked Percentage Bar Chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to create an overlayed stacked percentage bar chart. My data (so far) has:

- A column with 4 project names
- Three columns (1 for each month (quarter)), with a number of work items
- A column for the number of completed items
- A "Bar" column for the thickness of the bar I'd like displaying progress

This is what my data looks like, so far:

```
Name    Jan     Feb     Mar     Done    Bar
IVS     27      42      31      60      0.75
GCS     23      41      36      55      0.75
CT      17      60      23      79      0.75
ATS     30      36      34      35      0.75
```

Here's the result I'm looking for:

[Mock-up of desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOBzC.png)

This mock-up shows:

- The number of monthly work items display in monthly segments
- The total number of monthly work items represented as 100%
- The bar represents the percentage completed of the overall total monthly numbers

I was hopeful when I found this post: [Excel bar chart with gradient values (not percentages) and value lines](https://superuser.com/questions/1341477/excel-bar-chart-with-gradient-values-not-percentages-and-value-lines#new-answer). However it uses the fixed value stacked chart, not the percentage stacked chart. When I attempt to do the same steps with the percentage stacked chart, I don't get the same result.

Here are the steps I'm taking -- where am I going wrong?

- [Created 100% Stacked chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HxVF.png)
- [Pasted "Done" column into bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP1n1.png)
- [Change series to Secondary Axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2DGX.png)
- [Pasted "Bar" column into bar chart, set to Secondary axis, set "Done" series to "No fill" & changed Gap Width to 80%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lBdx.png)

As you can see, no "Bar" appears, but instead, the remainder of the rows are filled...

**EDIT**

Here's how I changed the setting (as you described by cybernetic.nomad): [Change Chart Type dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YceO5.png)

I get this: [Chart with non-percentage based Bar position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ig3GL.png)

I tested it with new data so the months would be in equal thirds and the bar at the 50% mark -- however, the bar isn't percentage, so gives odd results...

**EDIT**

I added a couple columns to create a total of the 3 columns and one to input the amount of work completed. Then I changed my "Done" column to "%". The bar now appears in the correct location, but again turned into a solid overlay (that extends beyond the chart).

[Overlayed chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT8Gg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "Stacked Bar" instead of "100% Stacked Bar" for the two series in the secondary axis:

[image]

The result should look like this:

[image]

If you absolutely want percentages, you will need to have your data match that:

[image]

Or introduce a new column with a calculated % of completion:

[image]

Create the chart as above, for the secondary axis, use `0` and `1` as the lower and upper bounds then format the numbers as percentages:

[image]

Comment: I didn't have the same menu as you, but was able to figure out how to change it. Why is the secondary scale different?

Comment: You can change the bounds of the axis by right-clicking on it and choosing "Format Axis", Choosing an upper bound of 100 should fix the problem

Comment: Please see my edits above -- the secondary axis is not working as a percentage as I'd expect...

Comment: See edits to my answer

Comment: Choosing 100 makes it a fixed scale. One project might have 130 items another 12. Making it a fixed axis won't work because 6 completed items is only 5% of the first project's work while it's 50% of the later one.

Comment: I thought the "done" column represented the percentage of completion. if not, please explain your data some more. or generate a column with the needed percentage

Comment: It does. In my first "Edit" I showed what happens to the chart by using a fixed upper bound: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ig3GL.png All of those bars should be at the 50% mark.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104844/discussion-between-cybernetic-nomad-and-richardlpalmer).